# Prove: $\alpha \beta = 1 = \beta \alpha$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The following question is from an introduction to group theory  by Rotman:

For each $\alpha \in S_X$, prove that there is $\beta\in S_X$ with $\alpha \beta = 1 = \beta \alpha$ (Hint: let $\beta$ be the inverse function go the bijection $\alpha$)

Answer attempt: Let there be $\alpha \in S_X$ this is a permutation, this is a bijection, and for all bijection there is an inverse function in this case we will call it $\beta\in S_X$

Let $k\in X$ therefore:
$\alpha \beta(i_k)=\alpha(k)=i_k$

On the other hand:

$\beta \alpha(k)=\beta(i_k)=k$

But this does not show that $\alpha \beta = \beta \alpha$, looking in an example: if $\alpha(1)=5$ so $\beta(5)=1$ but

$$\alpha\beta(5) \neq \beta\alpha(1)$$

What am I missing?

Comment: We want $\alpha\beta(5)=\beta\alpha(5)=5$ and $\alpha\beta(1)=\beta\alpha(1)=1$, not $\alpha\beta(5)=\beta\alpha(1)$

Comment: It is as though you wrote $\alpha\beta(x)\ne \beta\alpha(y)$. Of course  they're different, unless $x=y$!

Comment: But we have to prove that $\alpha\beta = 1 = \beta \alpha$ doesn't implies that $\alpha \beta = \beta \alpha$?

Comment: Remember that $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha\beta$, and $\beta\alpha$ are permutations; permutations are the same if they map the same element to the same element; and the identity permutation ("$1$") maps each element to itself.  $\alpha\beta=1$ means $\alpha\beta(k)=k$ for all $k\in X$, and $\beta\alpha=1$ means $\beta\alpha(k)=k$ for all $k\in X$

Comment: But $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$ – for the *same* $x$.

Comment: But $\alpha$ can take only $1$ as an input and $\beta$ can take only $5$ as an input.
So $\alpha \beta (1)$ is undefined

Comment: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are permutations, they must map all elements of $X$; and if $\beta $ is the inverse of $\alpha$, then $\alpha\beta$ is the identity, i.e., $\alpha\beta(1)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Of course
$$
5=\alpha\beta(5)\ne \beta\alpha(1)=1,
$$
since $1\ne 5$

However,
$$
1=\alpha\beta(1)= \beta\alpha(1)=1, \quad \text{and}\quad
5=\alpha\beta(5)= \beta\alpha(5)=5.
$$

Comment: But $\alpha(1)=5$ and $\beta(5)=1$ isn't $\beta \alpha (5)$ undefined?